# ASP Core Identity Server 4 Difference between Client Cors and start up Configuration Cors

Tags: authorization, identityserver4

For Identity Server 4, I would like to know the difference between adding a Client specific CORS
`new client() {client.AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>() { "http://localhost:4222" };}`
and Adding the set up in Startup.cs Configure

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("Origin")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
```

For context I've recently been learning about the methods ReactJS SPA needs to use when accessing Single Sign-on through another party, and as it stands I have implemented the Library 'oidc-client-js' and use the Authorisation code flow with PKCE because that it the standard implementation, and everything works. But I need help in understanding something:

1. If I remove the Cors options in StartUp the authorisation will fail and return a
   `origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`, why is the client Cors setting not enough? (is it maybe used further down the line with an API call?)

Any information you know of would really help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

IdentityServer is implemented as a middleware, same the ASP.NET Core CORS middlware.

You need to add CORS to the IdentityServer module because you want for example be able to restrict your CORS settings per IdentityServer client.

The ASP.NET Core CORS module will handle everything that IdentityServer does not catch, like request for REST API's that you have implemented your self.

[image]

Hope this helps. So, define CORS in IdentityServer for request to the API's that IdentityServer provides (like UserInfo endpoint) and the other CORS settings for your own API's.

Comment: Once one adds a [Client specific CORS](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity/blob/53f7c49c038202fe3e04b74b317b4ddfef0e5e3d/Bejebeje.Identity/Configuration/Config.cs#L49), does one need to do anything else? Right now, that's all I've done, but I'm getting a CORS error when making an AJAX request. [project on GitHub](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity/tree/main/Bejebeje.Identity)

Comment: I don't see any CORS settings in your Startup class, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I thought because I had [`app.UseIdentityServer()`](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity/blob/53f7c49c038202fe3e04b74b317b4ddfef0e5e3d/Bejebeje.Identity/Startup.cs#L191), IdentityServer will handle that CORS stuff for me, especially the client configured ones? Are you saying as well as the Client configured ones, I have to set the same thing via middleware?

Comment: IdentityServer's build in cors only deails with API requests to identityServers own API's, but if you add your own API's, then IdentityServer does not care about those... that's why  you need to add the ASP.NET Core one as well. see my picture above.

Comment: Exactly, and I am not calling my own API, I am calling IdentityServer's own APIs, so I'm confused why the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` isn't set. Basically, [this is my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65290589/ajax-call-to-an-action-with-authorize-attribute-in-net-core-3-1?noredirect=1#comment115448180_65290589).

Comment: see my answer on that question.