# AJAX call to an Action with Authorize attribute in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

On my [pet project](https://bejebeje.com/artists/xelil-xemgin/lyrics/govenda-sera) (a lyrics website), I wish to add "like" functionality, like this:

[image: screenshot showing like button]

Code is open source ([here's my current branch](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje/tree/feature/lyric-likes)). A click on the heart icon should add a like to the databse for the logged in user, and if the user isn't logged in, it should redirect to the login page (IdentityServer 4, separate project and domain).

**Controller Action:**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("lyrics/like/{lyricId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Like(
  int lyricId)
{
  try
  {
    string userId = User.GetUserId().ToString();

    await _lyricsService.LikeLyricAsync(userId, lyricId);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }
  catch
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }
}
```

**JavaScript on the View**:

```
<script>
  docReady(function () {
    let likeBtn = document.getElementById('like-btn');

    let likeLyric = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('attemping to like a lyric!');

      // 1. create a new XMLHttpRequest object
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // 2. configure the request
      request.open('GET', 'https://localhost:5001/lyrics/like/@Model.Id');

      // 3. send the request over the network
      request.send();

      // 4. this will be called after the response is received
      request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status != 200) {
          // analyse http status of the response
          alert(`Error ${request.status}: ${request.statusText}`);
        } else {
          // show the result
          alert(`Done, got ${request.response.length} bytes`); // response is the server response
        }
      };

      request.onprogress = function (event) {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
          alert(`Received ${event.loaded} of ${event.total} bytes`);
        } else {
          alert(`Received ${event.loaded} bytes`); // no Content-Length
        }
      };

      request.onerror = function () {
        alert("Request failed");
      };
    }

    likeBtn.addEventListener('click', likeLyric);
  });
</script>
```

I tried to expand on the `request.onload` function by adding an:

```
else if (request.status === 302) {
  window.location = request.response;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to get to that, the `.send()` fails. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's a screen grab of what is happening:

[image]

The error is:

```
attemping to like a lyric!
govenda-sera:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5006/connect/authorize?client_id=bejebeje-mvc-local&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid&code_challenge=2mUDM3-gR1jhn7E2EY7T17FkPTHikE8v-KQOBMskazM&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637437449511000684.OWQ3MTM4MjItOTJhOS00YjgzLTk1OTYtYWE2ZGUyMzRlYzUyOWE1MTkwNjgtNzI2YS00OWJjLTgzYjAtOTY1MDQ1ZDU3YzE1&state=CfDJ8DxKnFiqfK1HscY3j3s4hc-YvLoUa_X_46X1CclU7U-RahgrNQULQOLJu6943zTWCYa5Q5acO7g7vx03ddXSOOKkUtxZQAMHSgnQHFzBvhXnoC2i6yS0PpGxns7oA7tuvcgnp-jxub7RePZl5QAe5BwfXWkyHtMkFAmTkuultwz5w-Duenyb4KNrZRk1RLn6TLL93BS6YfIfoozorOnvKel4cFFjxIc7F_QXgVFKZm6ud5lN2nItw5WhkDfU6qMHhUUSQXQRJqWSit4CW_1hPpbHZhJmatXWxD8mLVFcSEKMNQz2UIU00RDxBCQW09Skuy3Uoz50Vwp4dEYPtNIcolIKrLn1pJguNsYRWBw391uWO7rMy9W5DPJV44fMVe8UR5xKNUarkelFX4CzHidF-rE&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0' (redirected from 'https://localhost:5001/lyrics/like/938') from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
govenda-sera:131 GET https://localhost:5006/connect/authorize?client_id=bejebeje-mvc-local&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid&code_challenge=2mUDM3-gR1jhn7E2EY7T17FkPTHikE8v-KQOBMskazM&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637437449511000684.OWQ3MTM4MjItOTJhOS00YjgzLTk1OTYtYWE2ZGUyMzRlYzUyOWE1MTkwNjgtNzI2YS00OWJjLTgzYjAtOTY1MDQ1ZDU3YzE1&state=CfDJ8DxKnFiqfK1HscY3j3s4hc-YvLoUa_X_46X1CclU7U-RahgrNQULQOLJu6943zTWCYa5Q5acO7g7vx03ddXSOOKkUtxZQAMHSgnQHFzBvhXnoC2i6yS0PpGxns7oA7tuvcgnp-jxub7RePZl5QAe5BwfXWkyHtMkFAmTkuultwz5w-Duenyb4KNrZRk1RLn6TLL93BS6YfIfoozorOnvKel4cFFjxIc7F_QXgVFKZm6ud5lN2nItw5WhkDfU6qMHhUUSQXQRJqWSit4CW_1hPpbHZhJmatXWxD8mLVFcSEKMNQz2UIU00RDxBCQW09Skuy3Uoz50Vwp4dEYPtNIcolIKrLn1pJguNsYRWBw391uWO7rMy9W5DPJV44fMVe8UR5xKNUarkelFX4CzHidF-rE&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0 net::ERR_FAILED
likeLyric
```

Comment: Do you have any return values or console error?

Comment: How silly of me, my apologies, I have added a screen grab of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do an AJAX call to this URL to login the user:

https://localhost:5006/connect/authorize?....

If you want the user to login/authenticate, then you need to redirect the browser to that page.

Or better, don't show the heart icon if the user is not logged in, better to have a login to like button? The user might otherwise be surprised why he needs to login.

Comment: I do want to redirect via `window.location = login url` on the javascript side of things, but it isn't letting because it is blocked via CORS. As for the UX, on the initial click of the heart icon, they'll get a UI interaction of some sort to inform them that a login is required, then they can choose to proceed, but perhaps you're right, I should think of a better way.

Comment: Its important that you also don't try to iframe IdentityServer, the user should see the full identityserver login page.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by cors, you need to enable cors in backend.

```
public class Startup
{

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowOrigins",
                          builder =>
                          {
                              builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                  "http://www.contoso.com");
                          });
    });

    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors("AllowOrigins");

    //...
  }
}
```

In addition, can you switch to another browser to access correctly?